# JavaFX grid panel's cells not intercepting events

Tags: java, javafx

I got a bit of a problem for a project

Basically I got a *game* grid pairs of symbols placed on it, and the goal of the game is to link two similar symbols between them.

So I created the game grid which is a gridPanel, and for each cells I add three events to check what kind of path the user is going to draw when dragging the mouse.
Then I added two events to the gridPanel to know when user is clicking the window (so that the path don't get drawn when the user didn't click on the mouse).

```
    id = new GridPane();
    for (int i = 0; i < id_grille.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < id_grille[i].length; j++) {

            etatCase = "";
            if (id_grille[i][j] != 0) {
                etatCase += id_grille[i][j];
            }
            final Text t = new Text(etatCase);
            t.setWrappingWidth(60);
            t.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 60));
            t.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
            id.add(t, j, i);

            t.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    if (t.getText() != "") {
                        VueControleur.EtatClic = t.getText();
                        System.out.println("Souris cliquee\n Etat Clic = " + VueControleur.EtatClic);
                    }
                }
            });

            t.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { // Quand on passe sur une case
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("Souris hover");
                    if (VueControleur.estCliquee && startId_grille[id.getRowIndex(t)][id.getColumnIndex(t)] == 0) {
                        System.out.println("================================================================");
                        t.setText(VueControleur.EtatClic);
                    }
                }
            });

            t.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { // Quand on sort d'une case

                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    // System.out.println("souris sortie");
                    if (!VueControleur.estCliquee && startId_grille[id.getRowIndex(t)][id.getColumnIndex(t)] == 0) {

                    }
                }

            });
        }
    }
    id.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            VueControleur.estCliquee = true;
            System.out.println("Grille cliquee");
        }

    });
    id.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            VueControleur.estCliquee = false;
            System.out.println("relache !!!!");
        }
    });
```

And the problem is that when I click on the grid the setOnMousePressed event of the grid get called but not the event of each cells.

It's like the event get "consumed" by the grid eventhandler

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: Okay guys, I found the problem which is that the OnMouseEntered/Exited/Pressed are not called when the button of a mouse is Clicked.

Howerver I'm still looking for which event handler can do the same as OnMouseEntered/Exited/Pressed but when a mouse button is clicked.

Comment: For better help consider posting [mcve]. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21741037/3992939)